# How can I check if a Perl string contains letters?

Tags: regex, perl

In Perl, what regex should I use to find if a string of characters has letters or not?
Example of a string used: `Thu Jan  1 05:30:00 1970`

Would this be fine?

```
    if ($l =~ /[a-zA-Z]/)
 {
    print "string ";    
 }
 else
 {      
    print "number ";    
 }
```

Comment: What is "alphabet(s)"? I suggest to give an example of the string you want to match.

Comment: Aaron: It's a common mistake for "letters". Mostly from people with Indian background.

Comment: what is it that you want to do with the string Thu Jan 1 05:30:00 1970 ? I don't really get it.

Comment: I want to check if it has letters in it or not.

Comment: If you are trying to parse dates, you should consider a date parsing module.  http://datetime.perl.org/?Modules

Answer (score 15, accepted):

try this:

```
/[a-zA-Z]/
```

or

```
/[[:alpha:]]/
```

otherwise, you should give examples of the strings you want to match.

also read `perldoc perlrequick`

Edit: @OP, you have provided example string, but i am not really sure what you want to do with it. so i am assuming you want to check whether a word is all letters, all numbers or something else. here's something to start with. All from perldoc perlrequick (and perlretut) so please read them.

```
sub check{
    my $str = shift;
    if ($str =~ /^[a-zA-Z]+$/){
        return $str." all letters";
    }
    if ($str =~ /^[0-9]+$/){
        return $str." all numbers";
    }else{
        return $str." a mix of numbers/letters/others";
    }
}

$string = "99932";
print check ($string)."\n";
$string = "abcXXX";
print check ($string)."\n";
$string = "9abd99_32";
print check ($string)."\n";
```

output

```
$ perl perl.pl
99932 all numbers
abcXXX all letters
9abd99_32 a mix of numbers/letters/others
```

Comment: The [a-zA-Z] takes a particularly American view to letters. It's a bigger world out there. The POSIX character class would be better, but matching the Unicode Letter property is the same thing and easier to type. :)

Comment: `/[a-zA-z]/` <-- the second z is probably meant to be uppercased (`/[a-zA-Z]/`), or the first `a-z` should be omitted (see my example)

Answer (score 9):

If you want to match Unicode characters rather than just ASCII ones, try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

while (<>) {
  if (/[\p{L}]+/) {
    print "letters\n";
  } else {
    print "no letters\n";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you're looking for any kind of letter from any language, you should go with

```
\p{L}
```

Take a look on this full reference: [Unicode Character Properties](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html)

Answer (score 0):

Using `/[A-Za-z]/` is a US-centric way to do it. To accept any letter, use one of

- `/[[:alpha:]]/`
- `/\p{L}/`
- `/[^\W\d_]/`

The third one employs a double-negative: not not-a-letter, not a digit, and not an underscore.

Whichever you choose, those who maintain your code will certainly appreciate it if you stick with one consistently!

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to detect whether something looks like a number for the purposes of manipulating it in Perl, you'll want [Scalar::Util](http://perldoc.perl.org/Scalar/Util.html)::looks_like_number (core since perl 5.7.3). From [perlapi](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlapi.html#looks_like_number):

> looks_like_number
>
> Test if the content of an SV looks
>   like a number (or is a number). Inf
>   and Infinity are treated as numbers
>   (so will not issue a non-numeric
>   warning), even if your atof() doesn't
>   grok them.

Answer (score 0):

```
[^\W0-9_]

# or

[[:alpha:]]
```

See perldoc [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)